# mIRC - User Level Command

Tags: command, mirc, aliases

I am currently working on a Twitch bot and I'm looking for a way that if I type something like `!ulevel [user nick] [user level]` into the twitch chat it will change the person with that nickname to the user level specified. I don't know if this will be possible but if so I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
on +3:text:!ulevel & &:#gamingtom:{
  if ($nick == gamingtom) { auser $3 $2 }
}
```